# How to remove part of a string with php?

Tags: php

Hello guys so I have a string where the begin part is the same

the string looks like this where the begin part is always ../images/

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
```

but the image2.jpg can be something like image_23423.png

how can I remove the ../images/ part?

I tought about str_replace but Could not get it to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://dk1.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename) would be helpful for you.

```
<?php
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$img = basename($img); //holds just `image2.jpg`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP explode to separate the strings

http://www.php.net/explode

http://php.net/array_pop

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";

$parts = explode('/', $img);

$img = array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways:

**[basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):**

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$img = basename($img);
```

**[explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [end](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.end.php):**

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$parts = explode('/', $img);
$img = end($parts); // takes the last element in $parts
```

**[explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_pop](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-pop.php):**

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$parts = explode('/', $img);
$img = array_pop($parts);  // takes the last element in $parts and removes it
```

**[str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):**

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$img = str_replace('../images/', '', $img);
```

*There are more ways to do this, but those are the most important ones.*

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$img = str_replace('../images/', '', $img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $imgout = str_replace("../images/", '', $img);
```

or use `explode()`

```
 $imgout = explode('/', $img);
 $imgname = $imgout[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

`pathinfo()` will suitably extract the information you need from the string. See https://www.php.net/pathinfo

```
$img = "../images/image2.jpg";
$imgDetails = pathinfo($img);
$imgName = $imgDetails['basename'];

print_r($imgDetails); // Will show you what other formats you can get the filename in, including extension etc.
```

`basename()` is also exposed as a function which you could use

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**PHP**

```
$path = "../images/image2.jpg";
$path_arr = explode("/", $path);
echo $path_arr[0]; // ..
echo $path_arr[1]; // images
echo $path_arr[2]; //  image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$subject = 'REGISTER 11223344 here';
$search = '11223344'
$trimmed = str_replace($search, '', $subject);
echo $trimmed
```